# Flask HTTP Server won't allow upload of multiple files at once

Tags: python, flask

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/home/ubuntu/shared/'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return """
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p><input type="file" multiple="" name="file">
         <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    <p>%s</p>
    """ % "<br>".join(os.listdir(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, debug=False)
```

If I launch the server and select 2 files through the form, it only uploads one of them. I tried for serveral hours and read about 15 topics on it, including the documentation.
Nada :c

Edit:
I also tried changing:

```
        file = request.files['file']
```

into:

```
        file = request.files.getlist('file')
```

would not work either. The type of quotes have no effect either. Wasn't that a python3 thing?

Comment: One thing I notice is that you're using the docstring to enclose your double quotes. Use single quotes instead, the triple quote has a special purpose in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os, ssl
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/home/ubuntu/shared/'
certfile = "/home/ubuntu/keys/fullchain.pem"
keyfile = "/home/ubuntu/keys/privkey.pem"
ecdh_curve = "secp384r1"
cipherlist = "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305"

sslcontext = ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
sslcontext.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
sslcontext.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
sslcontext.protocol = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
sslcontext.set_ciphers(cipherlist)
sslcontext.set_ecdh_curve(ecdh_curve)
sslcontext.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_data = request.files.getlist('file')
        my_pass = request.form['password']
        if my_data and my_pass == 'yakumo':
            for file in my_data:
                my_handler(file)
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return """
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <p><input type=file multiple name=file>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="">
        <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    <p>%s</p>
    """ % "<br>".join(os.listdir(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],))

def my_handler(f):
    filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
    f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, ssl_context=sslcontext, threaded=True, debug=False)
```

I made a very rookie mistake and didn't for-loop over the multiple files being uploaded. The code here was tested without issues with 4 simultaneous file uploads. I hope it will be useful to someone.

Edit: Code updated with some sweet TLS_1.2 and a password field. Enjoy a reasonably secure upload server. Password is transferred over HTTPS.